# Cycles Glare not working in editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glare

Already tried out Google, not one single video or forum helped me till now.

Emission is not glowing in the editor, only Eevee glowing there.

[image: The nodes, already tried out the Alpha, Noisy, Threshold, Imagine etc.]

[image: Cycles Render]

[image: Eevee Render]

Comment: What do you mean by *"...in the editor"*? For Cycles, you need the compositor *Glare* node as shown in screenshot 1. It only works post-render (F12), not in real-time in the viewport like Eevee's Bloom effect.

Comment: "not in real-time in the viewport like Eevee's Bloom effect." Exactly what i need, no way to enable this in the 5 million buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles tries to replicate real life - in real life, light doesn't "bloom" without something to show it - namely a volume of some sort. If you want to the glare to show in the viewport, you need to add a volume surrounding your emission lights:

[image: Volume1]

You can also add texture to the glare by texturing the volume:

[image: Volume2]

Comment: It's working in the Viewport shading Material preview mode, anyway to use this in the render preview too?

Comment: It should work in render preview as well. If you cannot see the "fog glow" in rendered preview, you might need to increase the volume density, or increase the emission strength.

Comment: oh im stupid, applyed to the wrong object, sry.

Answer (score 0):

The *Glare* effect works fine in the *Compositor* for both Cycles and Eevee. If you don't want to use the *Compositor* you can get this effect in Eevee with the *Bloom* option. In Cycles you don't have any *Bloom* option, that said you can use some tricks like:

- **Volumetrics**: Create a cube that contains your scene and give it a material with a *Volume Scatter* (with a low *Density* value) plugged into the *Output Volume*:

[image]

- **Layer Weight**: Create a sphere that contains your object and give it a material that is a mix between an *Emission* and a *Transparent* node, with a *Layer Weight (Facing)* as factor:

[image]